# Get the client application name connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I can get connecting client ip address using `CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address')` but can I get the application name that is connecting with SQL server? The problem is that in the client application server have a lot of applications connecting to SQL Server I just need to find which application is connecting?

Comment: Don't know that's possible. I doubt the client informs its name to the db engine.

Comment: Do you mean [`APP_NAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/app-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: It just returns .Net SqlClient Data Provider?

Comment: I believe your options here are the host computer name, and the login name. I use [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/downloads/) for this kind of troubleshooting. It's great. Check [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/161282/finding-the-application-behind-net-sqlclient-data-provider) on dba.se. Edit: As mentioned on that post, you can use `sys.dm_exec_connections` if you really want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Sure this is pretty simple. As @Larnu stated you use APP_NAME. You need to add this to your connection string.

Comment: Then that means you aren't passing the name of the application in the connection string. SQL Server has no idea what the application is unless the application tells it (much like you would have no idea where a person you meet is from unless they told you).

Comment: @Larnu do you have an example?

Comment: `Application Name=My Application;` like this

Comment: Do you even have the ability to update the connection string? That's a big assumption here.

Comment: [SqlConnectionStringBuilder.ApplicationName Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.applicationname?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: It is, @JacobH, but if they don't, then they need to speak to whomever can change it; as otherwise the OP isn't going to be able to get the name of the application (without a different application change, but then if they're changing the application, why not just change the connection string..?).

Comment: @Larnu that may be the case, but if he's using a 3rd party application then it probably won't be possible. We may come from different ecosystems. But where I work, almost none of our applications are built in-house. And if that is the case, the login name the application is using (or maybe port) might be helpful.

Comment: @JacobH indeed. one would, however, *hope* that the 3rd party application is well designed and *does* include the application name in it's connection string. :) But yes, I do also know the pain of some party applications (we have one at the office running on a OS written in 1979 :'( )